# How to create file .txt in a specific path of a directory

Tags: python

i want to create a text file in a specified directory. as shown below in the code, i am trying to create `di.txt` in `pathToOutputDir` but when i run the code, i find that `di.txt` is created as a yellow directory not a
as a text file that can be opened with notepad.

please let me know how to fix this code to create a `.txt` file.

**Code** :

```
def createOutPutDirectoryFor(self,directory):
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(pathToOutputDir, "di.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what you are doing wrong, as you didn't include the part in your code that creates the file/directory. However, you're most likely using `os.mkdir` instead of creating a file.

You can do the following to create the file:

```py
def createOutPutDirectoryFor(self,directory):
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(pathToOutputDir, "di.txt")
    open(pathToOutputDir, 'a').close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you create the path but don't actually create the file-
You can use the following to create the file:

```
open(pathToOutputDir, "x").close()
```

Comment: No, you're right it's not necessary to keep f.

Comment: to be fair tho, You are the only one that uses the designated file creation mode, which is great especially if the file already exists (although the answer that uses append wouldn't destroy the file either)

Comment: Yes, I think it is important to know what happens if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fullpath of that directory then

```py
def createOutPutDirectoryFor(self,directory):
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
    pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(pathToOutputDir, "di.txt")
    try:
        open(pathToOutputDir, 'a').close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        open(pathToOutputDir, 'w').close()
```